# Transformation of the maximum of a product

Tags: calculus, optimization

I am studying for an exam and I can't quite understand how to obtain the result below.

$$\max_{x\in [x_0-h,x_0+h]}|(x-x_0 + h)(x-x_0)(x-x_0-h)|   =  h^3\max_{u\in [0,1]}|(u^2-1)u|$$

I know how carry on from there, however I do not understand this particular step, it would be helpful if someone could show the smaller steps. (This is part of a problem in which I have to find the error formula with Chebyshev economisation).

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=(x-x_0)/h$. Then $x-x_0 + h= (u+1)h$, $(x-x_0)=uh$, and $x-x_0-h = (u-1)h$. Hence
 $$ |(x-x_0 + h)(x-x_0)(x-x_0-h)| = h^3 |(u^2-1)u |\tag1$$
The constraint $|x-x_0|\le h$ translates into $|u|\le 1$. But the right hand of (1) is an even function of  $u$. So it is enough to consider $u\in [0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Do you see that $(x-x_0 + h),(x-x_0),(x-x_0-h)$ are in Arithmetic Progression?

$\dfrac{(x-x_0 + h)+(x-x_0)+(x-x_0-h)}{3} \ge ((x-x_0 + h)(x-x_0)(x-x_0-h))^{\frac{1}{3}}$ from [Arithmetic-Geometric inequality](http://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/sjmiller/public_html/161/handouts/ArithMeanGeoMean.pdf)

Comment: I'm sorry, what is AP?

Comment: Arithmetic Progression. Sorry! Should  have have mentioned it before.. I have done it now.

Comment: Ah, yes. The common difference being h?

Comment: Yes. Do you know to use AM-GM inequality.?

Comment: I don't think I have seen it before.